# How to find PCI address of an ethernet interface?

Tags: ethernet, pci

is there a way to find out the PCI bus number of an Ethernet interface or vice versa. I am looking to write a Bash/Python script which gives some thing like

`pci_address = some_function(eth0)`

where pci_address is `sys:bus:slot:function`. How can these two elements be related to each other?

Comment: Tried `lspci` or `lshw` ?

Comment: I had used `lspci` but didn't tried `lshw`. Following command worked for me `lshw -class network -businfo`. Thanks @Serg

Comment: Glad I could help. I'll post this as an answer, then

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`lshw` and `lspci` are both capable of showing that information. As you have found out already, you can do `lshw -class network -businfo`. For instance, here's my output:

```
$ sudo lshw -c network -businfo                                                                                                                    
Bus info          Device      Class       Description
=====================================================
pci@0000:0e:00.0  wlan0       network     RTL8187SE Wireless LAN Controller
pci@0000:14:00.0  eth0        network     RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
```

What you also could use is `lspci -D` and pipe it to `grep` to filter out the ethernet controller specifically. Here's my example:

```
$ lspci -D | grep 'Network\|Ethernet'                                                                                                              
    0000:0e:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8187SE Wireless LAN Controller (rev 22)
    0000:14:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
```

Note that with the transition to [systemd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers), one could use of [Predictable Interface Naming](https://askubuntu.com/a/704364/295286) to just look at the interface name to find out PCI information.

Comment: The `lspci` doesn't provide the device name so in case of 2 identical devices it's not possible to distinguish which pci address and device name match

Comment: `lshw` works though, so still ⁺¹. But I agree, the information about `lspci` can probably be removed from the answer, it doesn't work for reasons mentioned in prev. comment.

Answer (score 25):

This information is available in sysfs, no helpers like `lshw` / `lspci` / `ethtool` / `udevadm` are needed:

```
$ grep PCI_SLOT_NAME /sys/class/net/*/device/uevent
/sys/class/net/enp4s0/device/uevent:PCI_SLOT_NAME=0000:04:00.0
/sys/class/net/wlp2s0/device/uevent:PCI_SLOT_NAME=0000:02:00.0
```

Comment: Not under vmware where there is no device symlink

Comment: Maybe because VMware's paravirtualized network device is not based on Ethernet?

Comment: Thanks. You are mostly right I soon discovered, but I couldn't find my comment to remove it. What had happened was the device was re-bound to igb_uio for DPDK, and so the original device nodes were no longer available.

Comment: Even more directly,  `$ ls -l /sys/class/net/eth0/device`
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov 16 16:30 /sys/class/net/eth0/device -> ../../../0000:07:00.0`
though `device/uevent` has a bunch of other useful stuff you might also need.

Answer (score 12):

ethtool will also show you pci for an interface (bus-info:)

```
me@ubuntu:~$ ethtool -i eth0
driver: i40e
version: 1.5.16
firmware-version: 5.04 0x800024cd 0.0.0
bus-info: 0000:06:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks you can tie them together by the IRQ.

```
ifconfig -a
```

will print the ethernet devices including Interrupt.

eg.

```
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:11:19:8b:77  
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:11ff:fe19:8b77/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:39958 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34512 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:21410099 (21.4 MB)  TX bytes:4802798 (4.8 MB)
          Interrupt:43 Base address:0xa000
```

while

```
lspci -v
```

gives the PCI info with IRQ

eg.

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0245
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    I/O ports at e800 [size=256]
    Memory at febff000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Expansion ROM at febc0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

since I see both are 43 I can infer that `eth2` matches `04:00.0`

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. lshw provided me a better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using `udevadm`

```
udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/net/eth{0..10} | awk '/device.*eth/'
```

`{0..10}` – checks the initerfaces from `eth0` … `eth10`

Therefore you could use this command

```
pci_address=$(udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/net/eth{0..10} | awk -F/ '/device.*eth/ {print $4}')
```

---

*Example output*

```
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/net/eth0':
```

Therefore the address is

```
0000:00:03.0
```

Or in your case with a single command

```
% pci_address=$(udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/net/eth{0..10} | awk -F/ '/device.*eth/ {print $4}')
% echo $pci_address
0000:00:03.0
```

or in a script

```
#!/bin/bash
udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/net/"$1" | awk -F/ '/device.*eth/ {print $4}'
```

Call the script with

```
script_name eth0
```

Output is

```
0000:00:03.0
```

Comment: Neat program, `udevadm` ! learned something new. +1

Comment: @Serg 
I needed a different solution ;)

Comment: @A.B. `lshw` and above approach are giving me two different results. Shouldn't both provide same pci address? cheers

Comment: @Waqas I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but `PCI_SLOT_NAME` in `uevent` isn't a PCI slot number, it is the bus.

On HP H/W you can use bus number to look up the PCI slot number from the output of `hplog -i`.

But I can't find similar utility for Oracle Linux on Sun H/W like M2s
You can get some information using `lspci -vmm` & looking for PhySlot entries.

This is for older systems before Dell's biosdevnames.